# $f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow$ {$(x,y):x^2+y^2=1$} by $f(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is a closed map

Tags: continuity, quotient-spaces, closed-map

> Define $f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow$ {$(x,y):x^2+y^2=1$} by
> $f(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$

I tried it by applying the definition of Closed map,but i'm unable to proceed.
Please give some  hint to prove it

**EDIT**

> Proof

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $[0,2\pi](Compact)$

$\implies A$ is compact(**Reason**:Closed subset of a compact set is compact)

$\implies$ $f(A)$ is compact(**Reason**:Continuous image of a compact set is compact )

$\implies f(A)$ is closed(**Reason**:Compact=Closed+Bounded)

Please verify the above arguments,especially the last one

thank you!

Comment: $f(0) = f(2\pi)$

Comment: You want to show the image of a closed set is closed. A closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @preferred_anon:Please check the solution!!

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi:What will be the use of $f(0)=f(2\pi)$?

Comment: Looks okay to me. I recommend posting as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $f$ is a closed map, we have to show the image of any closed subset of $[0, 2\pi]$ is closed in $S^1$. Let $K$ be a closed subset of $[0, 2\pi]$.

- First note that $f$ as a function $[0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is obviously continuous. Therefore $f: [0, 2\pi] \to S^1$ is continuous with the subspace topology on $S^1$.
- Recall that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact with the subspace topology if and only if it is a closed and bounded subset. Therefore $K$ is compact.
- Recall also that the continuous image of a compact space is compact also. So $f(K)$ is a compact space.
- Since $f(K)$ is a compact subspace in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it must be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since it's also a subset of $S^1$, it's also a closed subset of $S^1$ (with the subspace top).

Therefore $f$ is a closed map.